# Unable to debug JavaScript code in Visual Studio when starting to debug a web app in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, firefox, dom-events

I have set Mozilla Firefox as default browser and and MVC 2 web app when debugged from Visual Studio starts in Mozilla, I have checked Script option in Visual Studio debugging settings but it still does not want to stop an any break point in JavaScript. It says:

> "The break point will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

When using IE8 instead of Mozilla Firefox it stops on the break point.

The break point is set on button click event function.

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the IE browser in this way as different browsers have different API's for debugging. You can launch firefox, chrome etc when you run your project but not step through javascript.